# Why is this laptop taking almost 1 minute to boot Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: boot, 13.04, upstart, plymouth, bootchart

My dad's new HP Pavilion dv6 laptop running Ubuntu 13.04 takes almost a minute to boot up - it seems like it's hanging somewhere. Is there something I can do to easily fix it?

I need some help deciphering the bootchart. Here it is:

[image]

For better browsing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDY9W.png

Comment: I have an HP Pavilion dv9000 - it takes more time to boot up Ubuntu :(

Comment: How you generate this big graph? Thank you~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually don't see anything obvious on these things but here I do: Landscape.

There is a cluster of Landscape-related processes and one of these triggers `lshw`. These processes account for a massive amount of CPU use. In my mind they're almost certainly making the difference between 60 seconds and 30, maybe even 20 seconds.

Assuming you have support from Canonical (Landscape being a Canonical Support feature), I'd have a really serious moan at them directly. If you don't need it, remove it and try again.

---

If you need it and you can't get Canonical to fix it, all I can really suggest is you suspend or hibernate instead of shutting down. Depending on your machine, suspend can actually be pretty alright. Our second-gen i3 laptop will last for about 4 hours on power but will sustain ~96 hours on suspend (usually enough to get to a power supply).

---

And all an SSD is going to do is speed up the disk stuff. If you look at the second graph, you can see the first third is the only part that's doing any disk throughput. I'm not saying they're not good - they're awesome - but they're not going to fix your *problem*.

Comment: Thanks. I uninstalled landscape-client and landscape-common and it seems to be a bit faster. Installing the fglrx-updates driver also helped. It's still pretty slow, I'll need to run bootchart again, but maybe it's shaved off 10 seconds. I used to use landscape to manage computers but I can do without it for this one.

Answer (score 0):

Well Buy a SSD... My Compaq 6710b runs real smooth with a SSD ;) and boots up in no time.

Oh and don't worry about buying a SATA 3 SSD... SATA is downwards compatible. :)

Comment: +1 .... SSD will be the right option ...cauzz i have in my system ..and it take around 5 to 7 secs not confirmed, but its not more than 7 sec ....

Comment: I -1'd this because the graph is quite clear: only a small portion of this boot (10-15 seconds) is disk-limited. SSDs are awesome, but they won't cure a real problem.